# An easy partial dif.eq

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I try to solve this:
$$
\frac{\partial^{2} I}{\partial b \partial a}  = I.
$$
I guessed $ I = C e^{a+b} $, but it's not the general solution. So, how to find the last one?

Comment: "Easy" is **subjective**.

Comment: PDEs tend to have pathological solutions, absent some heavy boundary conditions.

Comment: Yes, I know that. So $I = \int\limits_0^{+\infty} e^{-ax^2 - \frac{b}{x^2}} d x.$

Comment: You can also take $I=C\exp(pa+b/p)$ for $p\ne 0$. Now you have two free parameters, which is definitely better than just one=)

Comment: @TZakrevskiy But PDE's solutions usually depend on functions, not just constants of integration...

Comment: @Evgeny that's why the smiley face=) On a serious note, the nature of free parameters depends on the type of boundary and/or initial conditions. I suspect that if we demand $I\in H^2(\Bbb R^2)$ (this can be seen as a boundary condition on infinity), then the only solution would be $I\equiv 0$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Hehe, got it :) By the way, can we use separation of variables here? Or power series?

Comment: @Evgeny For good initial/boundary conditions we can use power series, I think. The separation of variables - probably, but I don't see an immediate way to do that. What we can try is to change variables to obtain an equation of the form $I_{tt} = k^2 I_{xx} + I$ for a constant $k$. This looks like a wave equation and there some techniques to solve it - method of characteristics comes into mind, together with some explicit formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This equation has lots of solutions. For example, setting $I=f(pa+qb)$ where $p,q$ are reals, then $\frac{\partial^2I}{\partial b\partial a}=I$ becomes
$$ pqf''(x)=f(x). $$
which has the GS 
$$f(x)=C_1e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{pq}}x}+C_2e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{pq}}x}$$
where $C_1,C_2$ are constants. So
$$ I=C_1e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{pq}}(pa+qb)}+C_2e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{pq}}(pa+qb)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^{ax+b/x}$ is a solution for all $x\ne0$ and the equation is linear and homogeneous, a family of solutions is
$$
u(a,b)=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{ax+b/x}\,f(x)\,dx,
$$
where $f$ is a function such that the integral exists and $u$ can be differentiated inside the integral.

You can also construct solutions as series:
$$
u(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\,e^{ax_n+b/x_n}
$$
for appropriate $x_n$ and $C_n$.